# Python's script increased work time in Freecad

Tags: python, freecad

So I have a 500kb json file that I just iterate (or build a tree in FreeCAD, doesn't matter) and print values in console. In normal Python it takes about 200ms to end the output, but in FreeCAD it takes 40 seconds, plus it outputs it instantly after all the tanking. Same thing with a tree building in defalut Combo Panel. May be there is some setting to fix this issue? Version of python in FreecAD is 3.8.10.